# Having Issue with the Rss feeds in Wordpress

Tags: xml, wordpress, rss

I am trying to implement rss feeds on my site and i am using rss feed widget of wordpress,
When i put the url given by the client in widget, its gives me this Error

```
 "RSS Error: This XML document is invalid, likely due to invalid characters. XML error: Invalid character at line 117, column 35"
```

And here is that url :
http://www.odconsultingservices.com.au/feed/

I am using the old version of wordpress, is that a Problem?

Please suggest me some  Solutions ASAP,

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not your version of WordPress.  The problem is with the feed that you are trying to plug into the widget.  It contains an & character, which is invalid.

The Feed Validator lets you check the feed and see where the problem is:
http://feedvalidator.org/check.cgi?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.odconsultingservices.com.au%2Ffeed%2F

Two ways to fix this:
1) Talk to the people producing the RSS feed and ask them to properly encode the feed
2) Try to find a plugin that will fix the feed, or an RSS widget plugin that parses invalid XML.  A bit of Googling turned up https://wordpress.org/plugins/fix-rss-feed/, an old plugin that may do the trick